# Audio/Video Recordings of Tefilloth/Prayers

Tags: tefilla, blessing, amen, recording

Is there any concern with listening to audio/video recordings of Tefilloth (prayers)?  If someone hears a recording of a Berachah (blessing), does he have to say 'Amen'?  Is he prohibited from saying 'Amen'?

There's a fantastic video recording floating around of Cantor Helfgot during this year's Seliḥoth, which includes Kaddish.  I muted that part when watching the video.  Could I have listened to it?  Should I not have watched the video at all?

Comment: Regarding Amen, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3308/amen-for-recorded-brochos

Comment: I don't have time to research this now, but there's a mishna in Rosh haShana to the effect that you cannot fulfil your obligation of hearing the shofar if the person blowing it is inside a barrel or a tank or a pit. The reasoning, according to the gemara, is that you are not hearing the shofar but its echo. This is pertinent to your issue, seeing as you are not hearing the person's voice, but its synthetic transmission. You'd have to follow that gemara k'hilkheta, which I've not the time to do (sorry). Also, I love Cantor Helfgott. He should never be muted :)

Answer (score 2):

As to the first question, JEM sells [Davening with the Rebbe](http://www.jemstore.com/product_p/climbing_the_rungs.htm) which is a video of the Lubavitcher Rebbe being a Shliach Tzibbur.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe must have known of its existence, and yet didn't protest against it. Therefore, there shouldn't be any halachic issues (in addition to the fact that JEM does have Rabbonim on their staff).

Comment: Sources for your assumptions would help.

Answer (score 1):

1) No problem if it is at a Simha and it is with "Koved Rosh"(Yabia Omer Helek 3, Orah Haim 15).

2) Yes, prohibited from answering Amen (Yalkut Yosef Helek 3, 215:4).

3) You can answer Kadish if it is live (Yalkut Yosef 56:4), but not if it is recorded.

Comment: I edited it for you. Can you explain #2?

Comment: You are only allowed to answer amen to anything if it live.]

Comment: So what do you mean in #1 that it's no problem? What's no problem (since in #2 and #3 you say it is a problem to answer)?

Comment: @SethJ As for number 1) you can listen if it is at a Simha and if it is with Koved Rosh. 2) If it is not live then it is prohibited. 3) Kadish-live answering is permitted.